# get contact list with number and name in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show list of contacts with number and name .. for that i am using thia plugin `contacts_service 0.3.10` https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service

from following i can able to get name of contacts

```
 Iterable<Contact> _contacts;
_contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _contacts?.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Contact c = _contacts?.elementAt(index);
          phones = c.phones as Iterable<Item>;
          print(phones.toString());
          print('hbhj');

          return ListTile(
            leading: (c.avatar != null && c.avatar.length > 0)
                ? CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: MemoryImage(c.avatar),
            )
                : CircleAvatar(child: Text(c.initials())),
            title: Text(c.displayName ?? ''),
          );
        },
      )
```

now i don't know how can i access the contact number from above i can only displaying name of contact.

Comment: I think you need to query it using such a service: Iterable<Contact> johns = await ContactsService.getContacts(query : "john");

Comment: hey, is that working or not ?

Comment: have ACHIEVED it with another way , thanks for your response @NqbraL and its not working

Comment: Hi, @urvashi can you help me out, I am a beginner and am learning to do this. Can you post the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Contact c = _contacts?.elementAt(index);
String number = c.phones.first.value!;
```

use this to get the number